# Streaming video using raw sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to generate a live video stream and surface it via a UPnP framework.

I'm using the UPnP framework that was originally developed by intel available [here](https://openconnectivity.org/developer/specifications/upnp-resources/upnp-developer-resources/). It seems to have rolled it's own lightweight webserver.  I'm using FFMPEG to generate my video stream from images, I can set it up to feed it frames on a timer.  But how I manage the data that's generated?  How do I use send an HTTP response that could be a stream of unlimited length?

Is there a well worn technology to do this that I'm not aware of?

Any input would be great.

Answer (score 0):

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide possibly ffmpeg could listen on a tcp port, though that would require you to restart ffmpeg each time a client exits...and would only serve one client at a time.  If you want more than one client at a time you would have to use some type of real server...

Comment: It's not the input I need to manipulate, I need to get the output sent over HTTP. I am only worried about supporting 1 client at a time.

Comment: you'll probably need some type of server either apache or vlc or something to front end ffmpeg...

Comment: I've got ffmpeg generating the file into a memorystream.  The UPnP framework is already running a little mini-web server.  I just need to figure out how to set the headers correctly to make sure the consumer is correctly identifying the content.

Comment: unclear if there's anything within ffmpeg that would fit the bill.  Using a server as mentioned in that link might work.  Or are you trying to forward the bits through the intel server?

Comment: Looks like I could go either way.  I get to provide the content URL to the item the UPnP server lists for the content.  Looking into it now, it may be in my best interest to source some RTSP server code, and use that to server the actual content.